# extendscript system folder check

Tags: javascript, directory, exists, extendscript

I'm trying to build a dialog that will help with organization. Basically, it's pulling all the folders from our projects folder and sorting their names and putting them into a dropdown list. The user would then select whatever project they are working on, enter their initials, add a short description, and then finally add a version number 001. I've got that all working seemingly fine in the script below. An example would be

```
XXXPROJECTNAME_XXXINTIALS_XXXDESCRIPTION_001.aep

/Volumes/Nacho/Multimedia/PROJECTS/ABC_123_Teaser/01_AE/DW/ABC_123_Teaser_DW_TEST_001.aep
```

and we'd put that in an initialed folder inside our file structure, so
`/Volumes/Nacho/Multimedia/PROJECTS/ABC_123_Teaser/01_AE/DW`.

What I need some help with is checking to see if the folder already exists, and if it doesn't, create the folder. I would always know where the folder is supposed to be (/Volumes/Nacho/Multimedia/PROJECTS/ABC_123_Teaser/01_AE/DW), so I'd need a way to check it against another array of called folders. I feel like my logic is solid but coding skills are not.

If the folder does exist we then need to check and see if the file name exists already in that folder. If it doesn't, then save with the current name, but if it does exist then increment up from 001 to 002.

Super bonus points if anyone can explain how to make the progress bar work while the list of folders is sorting. I've got about 125 folders for it sort through which takes about 7 seconds. The way I have it now, the progress bar does its thing for about 7 seconds and then the list sorts for another 7 seconds. For now the progress bar is the least of my issues.

```
win=new Window("palette","AE Naming",[0,0,525,60],{resizeable:true,});
panel_1=win.add("panel",[5,5,525,57]);
downlist_1=panel_1.add("dropdownlist",[5,25,185,46] ,["PROJECT LIST"]);
edittext_1=panel_1.add("edittext",[190,25,250,45] ,"INITIALS",{readonly:0,noecho:0,borderless:0,multiline:0,enterKeySignalsOnChange:1});
edittext_2=panel_1.add("edittext",[255,25,380,45] ,"DESCRIPTION",{readonly:0,noecho:0,borderless:0,multiline:0,enterKeySignalsOnChange:1});
edittext_3=panel_1.add("edittext",[385,25,435,45] ,"001",{readonly:0,noecho:0,borderless:0,multiline:0,enterKeySignalsOnChange:1});
edittext_4=panel_1.add("edittext",[5,2,435,22] ,"FULL PATH NAME",{readonly:1,noecho:0,borderless:0,multiline:0,enterKeySignalsOnChange:1});
but_1=panel_1.add("button",[440,2,510,45],"SAVE");
progress_1=panel_1.add("progressbar", [5,0,510,5], 0, 100);

win.center();
win.show();

but_1.onClick = function() {
                        save();
                    }
{

var layerNameArray = new Array();    
var myFolder = Folder("/Volumes/Nacho/Multimedia/PROJECTS/"); //Search for all Folders in the projects directory
var myJPGFilesArray = myFolder.getFiles(function(f) {return f instanceof Folder});


if(myJPGFilesArray !== null){  
for(var n=0; n<myJPGFilesArray.length;n++){  
    $.writeln(myJPGFilesArray[n].name);  
var test = myJPGFilesArray.toString().replace (new RegExp("%20", "g"), " "); //removes the %20 which are spaces
     layerNameArray.push(myJPGFilesArray[n].name); //adds Folders to the Array
var sortMe = myJPGFilesArray.sort(); //Alphabetical sort

//////////////PROGRESSBAR ESTIMATED TIME//////////////
    while(progress_1.value < progress_1.maxvalue)
    {
        // this is what causes the progress bar increase its progress
        progress_1.value++; 
        $.sleep(35); //35 is about 7 seconds
    }
    $.writeln("Sorting Complete");
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

     downlist_1.add("item", sortMe[n].name); //Adds sorted Folders to the dropdownlist

downlist_1.onChange = function () {(downlist_1.selection)}
edittext_1.onChanging = function () {(edittext_1.text)}
edittext_2.onChanging = function () {(edittext_2.text)}
edittext_3.onChanging = function () {(edittext_3.text)}

 function save() {

//var combined = ("Volumes/Nacho/Multimedia/PROJECTS/" + downlist_1.selection + "/01_AE/" + edittext_1.text + "");
var aa = downlist_1.selection.toString(); //PROJECT
var bb = edittext_1.text.toString(); //INITIALS
var cc = edittext_2.text.toString(); //DESCRIPTION
var dd = edittext_3.text.toString(); //VERSION
var ae = "/01_AE/"; //where intials fodler should live
var slash = "/"
var underscore = "_"
var aep = ".aep"
var macVolume = "/Volumes/Nacho/Multimedia/PROJECTS/";
var folderpath = macVolume+aa+ae+bb;
var fullpath = macVolume+aa+ae+bb+slash+aa+underscore+bb+underscore+cc+underscore+dd+aep;

edittext_4.text = fullpath;
alert(folderpath);
alert(fullpath);

//Check to see if folder in folder path exists. if it does continue on. if it doesn't create a new folder.

//Check to see if the file name.aep exitsts AKA fullpath. If it does exist then version up. 001 becomes 002.  If not, just save as fullpath.

}
}
}
}
```

I know the solution is probably super simple, but I'm still very new to all of this, both Javascript and Extendscript, so sometimes the simplest things are the easiest to overlook. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It could be as simple as

```
if (!Folder(folderpath).exists)
  Folder(folderpath).create();
```

and

```
while (File(fullpath).exists)
{
   dd = "000"+String(Number(dd)+1);
   dd = dd.substring(dd.length-3);
   fullpath = macVolume+aa+ae+bb+slash+aa+underscore+bb+underscore+cc+underscore+dd+aep;
}
```

`folderpath` seems not to be used in your current code; I imagine it gets stuffed into the `fullpath` as well in your final code.

As it is, the 3-digit format for `dd` may lead here to an endless loop if `Number(dd)` is `999` and all versions exist. You may want to take that into account *now* or suffer the consequences in a while ;)

Comment: The if (!Folder(folderpath).exists)
  Folder(folderpath).create(); part worked perfectly!!!!! The while part not so much. It prevents me from overwriting the file 001 and I can still manually version up. But it doesn't version up if already detects version 001.

Comment: @Amaylayinsues: some debugging is called for, then. The `File.exists` stuff ought to work so it could be in the construction of your full path name.

Comment: `if (File(fullpath).exists)
{
   dd = "000"+String(Number(dd)+1);
   dd = dd.substring(dd.length-3);
   fullpath = macVolume+aa+ae+bb+slash+aa+underscore+bb+underscore+cc+underscore+dd+aep;
} else {
var target = new File(fullpath) //SAVE PROJECT
app.project.save(target);`

Comment: this allows me to save, any obvious mistakes that I'm making?  Thanks

Comment: Your code may increase `dd` only once. I used a `while` loop so the number increases as long as the next file also exists.